# How to store in file outputs of a c/c++ program in unix

Tags: unix

I have a program made on c++, let's call it `program`, which has a lot of output while running. I want to log that output on a file so is easier then to look at it. I tried already `./program & > file` `./program & |tee file` but it doesnt work (I want to run it in background if posible).

any idea?

Thanks

EDIT: It doesnt work `./program > file`. I tried putting it on background, on foreground, but the file is empty....

Comment: At least this worked for me: `>file ./program &`.

Comment: @tobi303 it might be irrelevant for you. I rather give more info than I should than less. Doesnt work = the file is empty.

Comment: What is this "c/c++" of which you speak?

Comment: @tobi303 you are right. FIxed

Comment: @tobi303: You don't need C++ code in the question for it to be a C++ question. Though I agree that this particular question is language-agnostic.

Comment: @tobi303: Yeah I'm nitpicking :) (was concerned other viewers may be misled though)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, nitpicking is the second favourite hobby for myself :P. Anyhow, I will delete the spammy comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect (`>`, `2>`, `2>&1`, etc) is the standard way of achieving this. However, this doesn't work in all possible scenarios.

Use `script` to capture *everything* displayed on your terminal:

`script -c "./program arg1 --arg2" output.log`

Comment: I experienced trouble with standard redirecting when building Android Framework. I believe this had something to do with spawning processes, which redirect was not able to catch anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect stdout and put the program to background use `(./program > file)&`

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
 program >& somefile &
```

then ending `&` means you want to put that job in the [background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process) and (with bash or zsh) the `>&` redirects both *stdout* and *stderr*

Then you could use `tail -f somefile` (perhaps in a different terminal window) to look at that growing `somefile`. See [tail(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)

BTW, there are other possibilities. Look perhaps into [`batch` command](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/batch.htm) (you may need to install the `at` package to have it) and into [nohup(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html).